# Windows Phone 7 Emulator: Where's the tab key?

Tags: windows-phone-7, emulation

I just downloaded the software and am trying out the emulator and I am surprised that it isn't obvious (to me) how to tab to the next enterable field.

The EN key means "English", not enter.
The bottom rightmost key IS the ENTER key, but that performs a submit of the page and strangely, results in the whole page being zoomed.

Where's the Tab key so I can set focus to the next enterable control?

[image]

Comment: If this could be of help... Windows Phone 6.5 has no tab key too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click the TextBox press PageUP then you can use your keyboard to input (and press tab to change textbox). I think there is no TabKey in SIP, no necessary if you have multitouch.

Comment: Interesting. iPhone has it, and I found it to be a clean way to jump to the next field, even if it is out of view. I guess the decision to leave it out is reasonable, I'll have to see how it works. Thanks for the tip about PageUp.I was expecting to just be able to use my PC keyboard w/o having to first hit any special key. BTW, what does SIP stand for here?